# What is the argument for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#something ul a').click(function(e) {
   ...
   ...
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

what is the e for and the e.preventDefault mean so i can understand what is happening here

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/: `.click( handler(eventObject) )` so it's the event object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `e` argument is the [`event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).
It contains information about the click event.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

---

The [`preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) prevents the borwser's default action for the event.
In this case, it will prevent the browser from navigating to the link.

Answer (score 2):

It's preventing the default action of the event, e.g. going to the URL, or scrolling the page to the `#location` in the `href`.

The first argument to any event handler in jQuery is [the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) itself.

Answer (score 1):

`e` is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), and prevent default is one of its functions.

Answer (score 1):

`E` is event and `preventDefaults` prevents browser from performing a standard operation in response to such an event. For instance if this is a click event on a link, `preventDefaults` whould prevent browser from redirecting to a linked page.

Answer (score 0):

The preventDefault() method prevents the borwser's default action for the event.
In this case, it will prevent the browser from navigating to the link.
shareedit